# Restore control data when returning to page

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0, lifecycle

I have a web app that has tabs to allow the user to switch between 2 views. The tabs are Hyperlinks. The page saves all form data to sessions, so I can use those sessions to restore the page data. The problem I'm having is how do I know when the Hyperlinks between the 2 tabs are clicked? Will I need to change those Hyperlinks to buttons, or not use tabs?
The tabs are in the Master page and are coded like this:

```
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelTabs" runat="server" CssClass="tabs">
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkNewEvent" runat="server" CssClass="tab" NavigateUrl="~/NewEventPage.aspx">Event</asp:HyperLink>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkStudentGroup" runat="server" CssClass="tab" NavigateUrl="~/StudentGroupPage.aspx">Student Groups</asp:HyperLink>           
        </asp:Panel>
```

When I come back to the NewEvent page, I want to restore the controls from data in the sessions:

```
        if (EventDetailSession.Current.details != null)
        {
            List<EventDetail> details = new List<EventDetail>();
            details = (List<EventDetail>)EventDetailSession.Current.details;
            foreach (EventDetail detail in details)
            {
                EventTitleTextbox.Text = detail.Title;
                EventNotes.Text = detail.Notes;
                EventStartDate.Text = detail.StartDate;
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone reads this looking for answers-- I was caching the page and therefore not reaching page load. Newbie mistake.